# mdoc warning: Empty input line #xx

Tags: bash

while searching man pages using `grep` ( `man tar | grep compress`) I am getting this error:

```
mdoc warning: Empty input line #xxx
```

*xxx can any number*

Is `grep` giving this error or something else? how can I fix this?

Comment: How are you searching man pages using grep?

Comment: man tar | grep compress

Comment: What system are you running this command. Is this some *BSD system?

Comment: It's not grep, but `man`. `man tar > /dev/null` will give the same warnings. Redirect the error stream to ignore then: `man tar 2> /dev/null | grep compress`.

Answer (score -1):

```
man -t tar > ~/tar.ps; open tar.ps
```

That will get you a tar manpage pdf suitable for framing.

Comment: This does not seem to address the given diagnostic message, who's producing it and what can be done about it.